# Regaining access to Linux server after SSH service dies?

Tags: linux, ssh, services

I recently ran into an issue with a VPS where the SSH service crashed, leaving me unable to connect to the machine.  The other services were up and running; only the SSH service died.
I managed to resolve the situation with a reboot from the VPS control panel, but the incident got me thinking:

Assuming:

1. I don't have physical access to the machine
2. I have no server control panel access or means of rebooting the server
3. All other system services are still functioning

Then how could I recover from the SSH service dying?

Comment: you will have to contact support. if you can't access the server and ssh was your only system level access, you will have to ask them for help.

Comment: @FrankThomas - But that's so un-MacGyver!  No savvy solutions like using FTP to edit the crontab?

Comment: I hear ya, but by calling you don't risk spending 30 years in prison due to misunderstandings. the CFAA is very unforgiving and prosecutors will do very unethical things to show a record of cyber-savvy convictions. RIP Aaron Swartz....

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is by making sure it doesn't stay dead. E.g. you'd often find it set to `respawn` in `/etc/inittab`. If `init` dies, your system will reboot anyway, and otherwise `init` can restart `sshd`.